# Создание приложение тест опрос

Tags: java, android

У меня такой вопрос, хочу для практики собрать приложение тест опрос, где будут вопросы и 4 ответа. Соответственно, нужно как выводить вопросы и изначально указав какой правильный и ответы. Я создал список `ArrayList` вопросы и `ArrayList` ответы.. вопрос как реализовать это, прочитал книги где были похожие приложения, но там хранятся тупо в классе, книги про `GeoQuiz` и `FlagGuiz` приложения.

P.S.

я в ресурсы добавил `arraylist` c вопросами и ответами, как выводить на экран вопросы из `arrayList` и так же выводить ответы и соответственно при этом указав какой ответ верный а какой нет ?